# bash selecting a range of line numbers, putting them into a new file, for each file in a dir

Tags: bash

So im sure im doing something dumb...

Im trying to run a bash script in a folder of .txt files.

for each file in the folder; Id like to select a range of line numbers and send them to a new file with "_Post" appended.

heres where im at.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.txt;
do sed -n 62,75p "$file" > "$file Post_B.txt";
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert `something.txt` to `something_Post.txt`,
you can strip the `.txt` and the end with `${file%.txt}`,
and then simply append `_Post.txt`, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.txt; do
  sed -n 62,75p "$file" > "${file%.txt}_Post.txt"
done
```

Comment: Nothing like a bit of *parameter expansion with substring removal* to come to the rescue.